# Tails of the Airy disk intensity formula?

Tags: mathematical-physics

The Airy disk intensity formula is given in the mathematical details section of the Wikipedia Airy disk article in terms of the Bessel function of the first kind.

I am interested in the asymptotic behavior of the tail of this function.  Is it exponential or powerlaw?  If powerlaw, what power?  Can you give a Taylor series expansion?
TIA.

Comment: (Moderators:  This is a very mathematical question.  Feel free to migrate it to Math SE if you think it will get better answers there.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering one wiki entry with another: The asymptotic forms of the Bessel functions are described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Asymptotic_forms). From the article,
$$ J_\alpha(x) \sim \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}} \cos\left(x - \frac{\alpha\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4}\right) $$
for large $x$, so $J_1(x)/x$ asymptotically approaches a sinusoid with power-law envelope proportional to $x^{-3/2}$. Thus the Airy pattern in intensity,
$$ I(\theta) = I_0 \left(\frac{2J_1(x)}{x}\right)^2, \quad x = ka\sin(\theta), $$
goes as the square of a sinusoid with an $x^{-3}$ envelope. Here $k$ is the wavenumber of the light, $a$ is the radius of the aperture, and $\theta$ is the angle away from the normal to the aperture.

Comment: Thanks for the very useful answer.  All those sines and cosines confused me.